# Leaving earlier than other co-workers; will this make me look bad?

Tags: work-life-balance, hours, resignation

I am auditing a course at a local university. It takes place one day a week and begins at 4:00. I am a contract worker and am only allowed to work 8 hours.  The earliest I can come in is 7:00 am, which means with break I could leave by 3:30 and still work all my hours.

I am worried this will look bad since most other employees are still in the office at 3:30. How can I explain to my boss that I am taking a course and although I will leave earlier than other employees on one day, I will still meet my weekly hours?

Comment: [Quite relevant, but not the same](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44945/how-can-i-stop-being-badgered-for-leaving-early-without-hurting-my-co-worker-r),

[And another](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12404/is-it-ok-to-leave-work-early-if-the-workplace-culture-accepts-it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I explain to my boss that I am taking a course and although I will leave earlier than other employees on one day, I will still meet my weekly hours?

Exactly as you describe -- stop by informally and explain to your boss your schedule and the reason for it. Ask if your boss has any issues with your working hours.

Your plan sounds reasonable to me, unless there is some policy that workers need to be in the office during certain core hours.

If your course is related to your work, that will only help in justifying your schedule.

Comment: Also, consider sharing this info with your colleagues as well (you never know where people will end up).

Comment: Alternatively, if someone complains about you leaving early, ask them loudly where they were at 7am when you started.